# If I have a struct object in global memory, do I need to malloc it? If that struct has structs as properties, do I have to malloc those?

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have two structs, `main_struct` and `child_struct`.

```
struct child_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
   // other properties
};

struct main_struct {
   struct child_struct child;
};
```

Also in global memory, I have a static struct:

```
static struct some_struct;

int main() {
...
```

Do I need to call `malloc` on `some_struct`, or is it allocated automatically? Do I need to call `malloc` on `some_struct.child`?

Alternatively, should I make `main_struct`'s `child` property a pointer instead of a direct value?

Comment: No you don't need (and can't) `malloc` for that global variable. That's not dynamic and exists for the lifetime of the process. As for whether the `child` property should be pointer - there's no right or wrong answer for that. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Would I have to `malloc` the `child` property?

Comment: No you can't. Think about it. The result of `malloc` is a pointer. There's no pointer anywhere in that code so where would you even store the `malloc` result into?

Comment: That would imply that `main_struct`'s `child` needs to be a pointer. But if I keep them as is, not using pointers, then do each struct's objects get recursively allocated?

Comment: It doesn't imply that need at all. You "can" make it a pointer and then use malloc. But it's not a "need to". As it stands the compiler will produce a binary that describes the size of the variable and the program loader will allocate static memory for that during process start up.